# Using CSVhelper to update a single column into a previously written CSV file . I have the code in Java but can't translate it into C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, translate, csvhelper

Essentially I have to read and update the CSVfile (only one column) with the current date **after** the test finishes executing(ie,there are some values written in at the start of the test execution and then I need to update the same file to input another value). I also have a DateTime error which isn't getting resolved no matter what I try.

**Sample of CSV start of test**

```
    RunId     ProductArea       Product         Component          PageObject   Control TimeTakenByLocatorJson
Run_645987    R201              BN2018.5         N778              BC1          C143
```

**CSV one column Needs to get updated after test
( TimeTakenByLocatorJson)**

```
    RunId     ProductArea       Product         Component          PageObject   Control TimeTakenByLocatorJson
Run_645987    R201              BN2018.5         N778              BC1          C143      2021-07-19
```

I've been trying to update a CSV file using **CSVhelper**. The code I have is in Java and when I tried translating the same code in C# it doesn't work.

**This is the code in Java**

```
public synchronized void writeEndCSV(String runId) 
    {
        CSVWriter csvWriter = null;
        try
        {
            String setupCSVLocation = Reporting.getSetupCSVLocation();
            CSVReader csvReader =  new CSVReader(new FileReader(setupCSVLocation));
            List<String[]> records = csvReader.readAll();
            for(int i=0;i<records.size();i++)
            {
                if(records.get(i)[SETUP_RUNID].equalsIgnoreCase(runId));
                {
                    records.get(i)[SETUP_TimeTakenByLocatorJSON] = Reporting.getExecutionEndDate();
                   
                }
            }
 
            csvReader.close();
            csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(setupCSVLocation));
            csvWriter.writeAll(records);
            csvWriter.flush();
            csvWriter.close();
 
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**This is my code in C#** (I'm new to .Net so I'm not sure about many parts)

```
     public void writeEnd(string runId)
        {
            var records = Enumerable.Empty<LocatorTime>();
            try
            {
                var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                {
                    // Don't write the header again.
                    HasHeaderRecord = false,
                };

                using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\Reports\" + runId + @"\LocatorTime.csv"))
                using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
                {
                    //csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<LocatorTime>();
                    records = csv.GetRecords<LocatorTime>().ToList();

                    foreach (var record in records)
                    {
                        if (record.RunID == runId)
                        {
                             record.TimeTakenByLocatorJSON = DateTime.Now;
                           }
                       // Console.WriteLine("inside loop");
                    }
                }//Endof Stream Reader
                
                using (var stream = File.Open(@"D:\Reports\" + runId + @"\LocatorTime.csv", FileMode.Append))  //not sure what the file mode should be 
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                {

                    csv.WriteRecords(records);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }//end func writeEnd
```

**This is the class used for the csv file & are also the column names in the csvfile**

```
    public class LocatorTime
    {
        
        public string RunID { get; set; }
        public string ProductArea { get; set; }
        public string Product { get; set; }
        public string Component { get; set; }
        public string PageObject { get; set; }
        public string Control { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeTakenByLocatorJSON //only this value needs to be written for update at end of exec        
        {
            get;
            set;
        }/*error because of DateTime datatype how to resolve?*/  }//LocatorTimeClass 

/*public void SetExeDate() //tried this for removing DateTime error, didn't work
         {
             DateTime today = DateTime.Today; // As DateTime
             string s_today = today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); // As String
             //TimeTakenByLocatorJSON = s_today.Trim();
             TimeTakenByLocatorJSON = Convert.ToDateTime(s_today);}

*/



    public sealed class LocatorTimeMap : ClassMap<LocatorTime> //is mapping helpful for updating? currently commented out
    {
        public LocatorTimeMap()
        {
            Map(m => m.RunID).Index(0);
            Map(m => m.ProductArea).Index(1);
            Map(m => m.Product).Index(2);
            Map(m => m.Component).Index(3);
            Map(m => m.PageObject).Index(4);
            Map(m => m.Control).Index(5);
          Map(m => m.TimeTakenByLocatorJSON).Index(6); //error
        }
    }
```

I had used the below link as reference for trying to update the CSV file hence the use of "HasHeaderRecord = false"
https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/writing/appending-to-an-existing-file/

Comment: Could you include CSV sample too?

Comment: I can't give a sample as I'm new on this site but as mentioned the column names in csvfile are the same as the methods mentioned, essentially the inside of the csv is like so RunID|ProductArea|Product|.....|TimeTakenByLocatorJSON

Comment: You can paste a section of the csv into the question and format it as code

Comment: Wouldn't you rather just use a database? You can produce a CSV on demand for any system wishing to consume a CSV but keeping your data in one, loading it all, looping through it, find it a record, setting a value, writing it all to csv again, lather rinse repeat.. that's like pulling fingernails out. You already have the entity, you could tell EF to make you a nice little sqlite db and this would be an absolute doddle, and much more efficient to reduce all that code to `db.Things.First(t => t.RunId == x).SomeDate = DateTime.Now; db.SaveChanges()`. Dare say it'd solve the date format issues too

Comment: @CaiusJard yes, but the task assigned to me was to translate that java code to C# using Csvhelper so I have to do that no questions asked

Comment: "Error because of DAteTime type" isn't really very helpful - *what exact error* ? Full type and message please

Comment: FileMode Append probably not what you want; it causes the streamwriter to seek to the end of the file, this means that new records will be written at the end. Effectively the file will double in length every time it is processed

Comment: You issues will probably resolve if you decorate your `TimeTakenByLocatorJSON ` property with a `[Format("yyyy-MM-dd")]` attribute - I think the mapping code is unnnecessary

Comment: Also, if you want the date as utc, it's `DateTime.UtcNow`

Comment: @CaiusJard I got two errors, one was 'string was not recognized as Valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at Index 0' when I used {get; set} When I used the modified code (the SetExeDate func) I got cannot implicitly convert 'string' to System.DateTime

Comment: Well, the code in SetExeDate is ... erm.. I don't really know what it's doing to be honest. `TimeTakenByLocatorJSON = DateTime.Now` would be fine, if the format is `yyyy-MM-dd`. The other error sounds like CsvHelper is getting bad data in the CSV. I note you've told CsvHelper that the file doesn't have a header - is that really true? It sure looks like it has a header in the sample

Comment: HasHeaderRecord = false; Are you talking about this statement? I had looked at this link for reference and had done exactly as given because here they show it for appending so I thought maybe with a few changes in code I could use it for updating as well https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/writing/appending-to-an-existing-file/

Answer (score 0):

I noticed 3 things.  1st - In your sample data, you have 7 column headers, but only 6 columns of data.  2nd - Your class names for "RunId" and "TimeTakenByLocatorJson" don't exactly match the columns in your sample data. 3rd - Your config says "Don't write the header again.", but you are using it for reading.

For the 1st issue, I'm going to assume this was a misprint and I'll add another column of data.

For the 2nd issue, there are at least 3 ways to handle it. You already handled it one way by mapping to indexes in `LocatorTimeMap`. I'll give you a 2nd way by casting the header to lower case.  A 3rd way is to use the [name attribute](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/attributes/)

For the 3rd issue, the header *is* there for reading and I assume you want the header when you write it, so you can leave `HasHeaderRecord = false` out.

```cs
void Main()
{
    writeEnd("Run_645987");
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here
public void writeEnd(string runId)
{
    var records = Enumerable.Empty<LocatorTime>();
    try
    {
        var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        {
            // This will convert both the header coming in and your class property to lower case.
            PrepareHeaderForMatch = args => args.Header.ToLower()   
        };

        var input = new StringBuilder();
        input.AppendLine("RunId,ProductArea,Product,Component,PageObject,Control,TimeTakenByLocatorJson");
        input.AppendLine("Run_645987,R201,BN2018.5,N778,BC1,control1,2021-07-19");
        
        using (var reader = new StringReader(input.ToString()))
        //using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\Reports\" + runId + @"\LocatorTime.csv"))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
        {
            records = csv.GetRecords<LocatorTime>().ToList();

            foreach (var record in records)
            {
                if (record.RunID == runId)
                {
                    record.TimeTakenByLocatorJSON = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
        }//Endof Stream Reader

        //using (var stream = File.Open(@"D:\Reports\" + runId + @"\LocatorTime.csv", FileMode.Append))  //not sure what the file mode should be 
        //using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            csv.WriteRecords(records);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}//end func writeEnd

public class LocatorTime
{
    public string RunID { get; set; }
    public string ProductArea { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public string Component { get; set; }
    public string PageObject { get; set; }
    public string Control { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeTakenByLocatorJSON //only this value needs to be written for update at end of exec        
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}//LocatorTimeClass
```

Comment: Thanks, your code worked halfway for me. While it DIDN'T update the file, it DID remove the Datetime error. Also about the `PrepareHeaderForMatch = args => args.Header.ToLower()` , since this is a small part of a much larger project is there anyway to read it without changing anything about the headers? And is there any other way to update the files using CSVhelper?

Comment: is it possible to use the map to update just one particular input? `input.AppendLine("Run_645987,R201,BN2018.5,N778,BC1,control1,2021-07-19");` instead of writing all the values lets say I just want to update control1 to control3, since I've mapped my class with indexes can I say just update that particular index? else How do I go about it?

Comment: Instead of `PrepareHeaderForMatch` you could use the `ClassMap<LocatorTime>` and either use the indexes you had or you could use `Name` in the ClassMap. `Map(m => m.RunID).Name("RunId");`  Or you could use the name attribute on the `LocatorTime` class.  There is a link for that above. I'm not sure about updating one particular input. You could append an extra line with those values, but if you want to actually change it, I believe you would have to read and then write the whole file again with that single change.